# JQGrid Parse Data from the rows

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

The following is the format of the JQGrid:

```
{ 
  "total":25,
  "page":1
  "records":107,
  "userdata": {"foo": "bar"},
  "rows": [...] 
}
```

I am looking for the JQuery code that will help me to parse the data that is returned into my `rows`. I have used the following code after getting the `ajax success` response and:

```
$.each(data, function (index, element) {
    if (index == 'rows') {
        $.each(element, function (index1, element1) {
            alert(element1 + index1)
        });
    }
});
```

But, in my inner `$.each()` i am not able to fetch the values of each element, can anyone help me to fetch all the element's data.

Comment: `"rows": [...]` what is in `[]` some object or string values.

Comment: @Jai its comma separated `string values`

Comment: i added an answer see that if works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why you have a if check for `'rows'` instead you can check directly like this:

```
$.each(data.rows, function (index, element){
    alert(element + index);
});
```

---

As per your latest comment:

*main concern here is to pick the first value from the string*
So for this you can have a check for the `index 0` like below:

```
$.each(data.rows, function (index, element){
    if(index == 0){
        alert(element + index);
    }
});
```

so here alert will come only for `index 0` [A demo fiddle about it.](http://jsfiddle.net/FLg5Y/).

Comment: yeah, its a good post, just wanted to confirm one another thing, now when i alert the `index`, its showing me the `cell`, show can i do more generic and alter my to `$.each(data.rows.cell, function(index,element)){});`, but when i do this it shows me an error

Comment: the error is `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: @HarshSharma would you post your `rows: []` to have a look at it.

Comment: 0,1,VanillaRetailWS,donotemail@mobilephonexchange.co.uk,,Vanilla Retail,Webservice,True,,1,1,True,,0,19/02/2014 11:41:31,01/01/1900 00:00:00,JHASD687HBASDHJKDSABAJH765NDHJSH123H,,False,,,,,

Comment: `cell` i don't see it here.

Comment: this is the cell value or you can say element of index

Comment: anyways i can apply one extra loop, but my main concern here is to pick the first value from the string, according to you whats the best way to pick a first value

Comment: @HarshSharma you can have a check for the `index == 0` as per updated answer.